# How to reference dynamically loaded assembly from runtime compiled assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly, roslyn

I have runtime-compiled assembly that references another assembly (DynLoadedAssembly) that is located in specific path and loaded dynamically. When I execute runtime-compiled assembly, I get an error: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException Could not load file or assembly 'DynLoadedAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies`.

Check out code:

```
    public string Run()
    {
        var text = @"
            using DynLoadedAssembly;
            public class DynClass
            {
                public static string Evaluate()
                {
                    return new SomeClass().Do();
                } 
            }";

        var dynAssemblyPath = @"c:\path\to\DynLoadedAssembly.dll";

        Assembly.LoadFile(dynAssemblyPath);

        var tree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(text);
        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
            "calc",
            options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary),
            syntaxTrees: new[] { tree },
            references: new[]
                {
                    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
                    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(dynAssemblyPath)
                }
            );

        Assembly compiledAssembly;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var compileResult = compilation.Emit(stream);
            compiledAssembly = Assembly.Load(stream.GetBuffer());
        }

        Type dynClass = compiledAssembly.GetType("DynClass");
        MethodInfo evaluate = dynClass.GetMethod("Evaluate");
        return evaluate.Invoke(null, null).ToString();
    }
```

Here `SomeClass` is defined in `DynLoadedAssembly` that loaded dymanically from dynAssemblyPath.

If I place `DynLoadedAssembly` into execution assembly folder - then it works fine.
Other workarounds are:

- specify probing (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w(v=vs.110).aspx) element in App.config
- use `AssemblyResolve` event handler

But I want to load referenced assembly dynamically. So my questions are:

- Why "Step 2: Checking for Previously Referenced Assemblies" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx#step2) failed? Why execuded code do not see `DynLoadedAssembly` library in current domain?
- How to make my compiled assembly find previosly loaded assembly in current domain?

Comment: What's wrong with using `AssemblyResolve`?

Comment: Runtime-compiled assembly constructed by a library, called ScriptLoader. And only that library must know about path from where plugins assemlies that are dynamically loaded, as well as all related functionality must be in that library. But error is thrown in outside code when executing constructed code - at a time when libraries, referenced by a compiled code, tried to be loaded. If I use `AssemblyResolve` - it will be in outside code, that does not meet the descripbed principles.

Comment: Why not just use the return value of `Assembly.LoadFile(dynAssemblyPath)`? Protip: If it is in a different folder, use `LoadFrom` instead to resolve dependencies correctly.

Comment: @leppie: If I specify reference like this: `MetadataReference.CreateFromAssembly(Assembly.LoadFile(dynAssemblyPath))` or `MetadataReference.CreateFromAssembly(Assembly.LoadFrom(dynAssemblyPath))` this isn't take any effect. Or may be you mean something different (to use the return value of `Assembly.LoadFile(dynAssemblyPath)`)?

Comment: @andrew: After reading your question again, the only way this can possibly work is via `AssemblyResolve`.